# Which is correct: "will resume" or "will be resumed"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

Here are the two sentences using *will resume* and *will be resumed*.
What is correct here? Also, is it true that *will* should always be followed by *be*?

> - My office process *will be resumed* once I complete 2 months in the state.
> - My office process *will resume* once I complete 2 months in the state.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical.

"Will" is followed by the basic form ("infinitive") of almost any verb (the only exceptions I can think of are modals like "can", "may", "should", none of which has an infinitive).

"Resume" is one of a large class of English verbs which can be used both transitively (of the person causing or initiating a process), and intransitively (of the thing undergoing the process). They are sometimes called [ergative verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb).

So *The chair resumed the meeting* and *The meeting resumed* are both possible.

Other examples are "roll" (*He rolled the trolley aside*; *The trolley rolled down the slope*) and "start" (*She started the car*; *the car started first time*).

In the transitive sense, these verbs can be used in the passive, so *The meeting was resumed by the chair*.

So in your example, both *the process will resume* and *the process will be resumed* are grammatical and idiomatic. There is a slight difference in meaning, in that *the process will resume* suggests that it will happen automatically without anybody needing to do anything, whereas *the process will be resumed* suggests that somebody will make it happen; but these are only suggestions, and may not reflect a real difference in the objective events.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your first question 'will' is not always followed by 'be'.  Sometimes 'will' is a noun, as in last will and testament.  Sometimes 'will' is followed by the simple form of a verb as in "I will go shopping".

"my residential visa application process will be resumed" what this means is that someone will resume the application process.  This someone might be a government worker.

"my residential visa application process will resume" what this means is that the process itself will resume.  Both a process can resume and a person can resume a process.

In 1 'will be resumed' is passive which means that the noun coming after the noun is the one doing the action.  For example, in "I was hit by Jim", that means that Jim did the hitting because 'was hit' is passive.

In 2 'will resume' is active so the noun before the verb is the one doing the action.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both is the tense. 'Will resume' is the simple future tense that implies that is will go back to what is was in the near future. While 'will be resumed' is the future perfect tense with begs the question of time. Both sentences are alluding to something restarting, the time line however begs the difference.  That is how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I beg to differ with the last comment: 'will resume' and "will be resumed' are both in the simple future tense, the 1st one is in the active form whereas the 2nd one is in the passive form.

Here's an example of the future perfect tense in both forms:

> I will have bought that book before the end of the week (active).
>
> That book will have been bought by the end of the week (passive).

The second one sounds very clumsy indeed but is grammatically correct.