# "Will be xxx- ing" or Will xxx"

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses, future-time, email

I wish to write an email about a decision taken in a meeting. Of the below options, which is the correct sentence to put in the email?

1. It was agreed that XYZ team *will conduct* a monthly review meeting with PQR on their open action items.
   OR
2. It was agreed that XYZ team *will be conducting* a monthly meeting with PQR on their open action items.

My confusion is around using the right set of words for an action that is planned to occur on a consistent basis in future.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please edit your question to explain what **you** think is the difference between these two sentences. You could google **future continuous** to get some ideas: include links to these references in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Will + be + verb -ing)" vs "Will + verb" ?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142165/will-be-verb-ing-vs-will-verb)

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/185619/48224 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/128951/48224 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48499/48224 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105912/48224

Comment: Thanks Davo. I have edited the question to make it more clear.